# How do I load and external swf AND gotoAndPlay() with ONE button

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, onload, goto, timeline

I've made an interactive tour which can be seen [here](http://www.92YTribeca.org/Tour).

The main swf is the nav at the top. And I load 4 external swfs into the main (About, Rentals, Floorplan, Neighborhood).

I need a button in `Floorplan.swf` to load `Rental.swf` **AND** `gotoAndStop("CAFE")` - a frame within `Rental.swf`.

This is the code that I am working with right now:

```
btnFLRcafe.onRelease = function(){ 

var loader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader(); 
loader.addListener(this); 

function onLoadComplete(loadedClip) { 
loadedClip._root.mcRENTALS.gotoAndStop("CAFE"); 
} 

loader.loadClip("maps_92Tri_RentalsMain.swf", 1); 
}
```

The code will load the swf, but it DOES NOT `gotoAndStop`. I've rearrange and rewrote - nothing worked. When I put traces on the code, it seems that `onLoadComplete` isn't even being called. I am at a loss.

I can send files if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a method for `onLoadComplete`, try adding one called `onLoadInit(loadedClip)`

---

Here is some basic code for what I think you are trying to do.
I have a main swf which has a button on the stage. On the button, I had the following actions...

```
on(release) {

    var loader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
    loader.addListener(this);

    function onLoadInit(loadedClip:MovieClip) {
        _root.contentArea.gotoAndPlay("ANIMATE");
    };

    loader.loadClip("Loaded.swf", _root.contentArea);
}
```

In the main move, I have another clip on the stage named `contentArea` where the `Loaded.swf` file will be loaded in. `Loaded.swf` has a frame label called `"ANIMATE"` which starts a small animation on the timeline.